# Laravel select from DB where in Collection - Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a DB, "views," with many, many entries. I also have a "Courses" table, which these views are one-many related to. In Laravel Nova, I can get a metric of all views over time for a course with some code like this:

```html
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->countByDays($request, view::where('viewable_id', $request->resourceId));
}
```

In this case, `viewable_id` is the id of the course, and `$request->resourceId` gives the ID of the course to sort by. Pretty simple.

However, now things get a little difficult. I have another model called `Teachers`. Each `Teacher` can have many courses, also in a one-many relationship. How do I get a metric of views over time for all the courses that teacher teaches?

I assumed the simplest way to do this would be to create a Laravel Collection with all courses the Teacher teaches (not exactly efficient), and then select all views in the database where `viewable_id` matches one of the courses in that list. Of course, by posting this, I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Of course, once this is figured out, I'd love to do the same thing for `Categories` (though that should function in a very identical manner to Teachers, so I don't need to ask that question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get a metric of views over time for all the courses that teacher teaches?

*This should be the "countByDays" of views where the viewable_id is in the list of course ids that the teacher teaches.*

An SQL query statement to achieve that is given below:

```
select * from "views" 
where "viewable_id" in (select "id" from "courses" where "teacher_id" = ?)
```

The Eloquent query should be similar to:

```
$this->countByDays($request,
  view::whereIn(
    'viewable_id',
     Course::with('teacher')
             ->select('id')
             ->where('teacher_id', $request->resourceId)
  )
);
```